# What is the return datatype for the function TZ_OFFSET in oracle?

Tags: oracle, timezone, timestamp, return, sqldatatypes

What is the return datatype for the function TZ_OFFSET in oracle ??

Eg,

```
select tz_offset(DBTIMEZONE) from dual;
```

-04:00

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it's `VARCHAR2`:

```
SQL> SELECT TZ_OFFSET('UTC'), DUMP(TZ_OFFSET('UTC')) FROM DUAL;

TZ_OFFS DUMP(TZ_OFFSET('UTC'))
------- --------------------------------
+00:00  Typ=1 Len=7: 43,48,48,58,48,48,0
```

The `Typ=1` indicates `VARCHAR2`, but note that the ASCII dump has the `,0` at the end. That means the string has a `\0`-type terminator. That's normally not the case for a `VARCHAR2` but still I'd just treat it as a generic string-ish type.

This may vary by characterset; I don't know for sure. The query I ran above was for an Oracle instance with `NLS_CHARACTERSET` = `WE8MSWIN1252` and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` = `AL16UTF16`.

---

**Addendum** - followup question asked how to turn `TZ_OFFSET` output into a number. Here's how:

1. Convert the hours portion into a number
2. Convert the minutes portion into a number and divide by 60
3. Add the two values together
4. Deal with the offset's sign (+ or -)

**NOTE**: *I updated this after realizing that it wouldn't work for a negative time zone offset that includes minutes. For example, my original equation (now removed) would have converted `-03:30` to `-2.5` instead of `-3.5`*.

Here's the full command:

```
SIGN(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET('whatever'), 1, 3))) * (
  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET('whatever'), 2, 2)) +
  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET('whatever'), 5, 2)) / 60
)
```

Note that the third `SUBSTR` specifies "2 characters starting at position 5" (`SUBSTR(..., 5, 2)`). Normally you'd say "from position 5 to the end of the string" (`SUBSTR(..., 5)`), but that will include the strange trailing null-char (`\0`, as seen in the `DUMP`), which will cause an error.

Comment: If it's varchar2 then why it's not allow me to change datatype number using "to_number" function.

Comment: One reason would be that a number does not have a colon in it.

Comment: @DavidAldridge is correct - the colon is causing the trouble. I'll update the answer in a minute to show you how you can change it into the number of hours, as a numeric.

Comment: @EdGibbs thank you very much..:) I got the exact answer what I need.

Comment: @sibimani - please check the updated answer. My original won't be correct for time zone offsets with negative hours and non-zero minutes, for example `-03:30`. I know there aren't many of those but they do exist. All others such as `+03:00` and `+03:30` and `-03.00` will work with the original, but the original will convert `-03:30` to `-2.5`. The updated version handles them all, and will correctly convert `-03:30` to `-3.5`.

Answer (score 1):

At least the JDBC driver reports it as `VARCHAR(7)`

[image]

And based on the value, there isn't any other possibility. No other datatype will let you combine numbers and leading zeros without applying some formatting.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET('whatever'), 1, 3) + SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET('whatever'), 5, 2) / 60
```

to convert the offset into a number?

Comment: Although I feel like hacky, I would end up doing this substring magic in the backend. However I do believe that doing this in the DBMS is way faster than sorting my way around in my C#! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As [ed-gibbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2091410/ed-gibbs) said looks like a VARCHAR2 with a \0 at the end. Here's how to search for time zone names based on time zone offset

```
SELECT distinct tzname,SUBSTR(tz_offset(tzname),1,6) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE SUBSTR(tz_offset(tzname),1,6) = '-04:00' order by tzname;
```